# split devnagri word into each character

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an devnagri image which is a word.

[image: devnagri image]
I need to convert this word into one character image. So this uploaded image will have 4 images, each consisting of one character.

Later, using these images of each character to convert it into devnagri text using CNN. This logic is already in place.

But i am stuck with the word to each character image conversion.